# show only one history by commit SHA-1 key

Tags: git

i have command in git Bash:

`git log -2` and it gave me results:

[image]

but now i want only show commit where number equals == `"ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949"` (first commit)

what's command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use git show:

```
git show commit_id
```

Or if you want to use log:

```
git log -1 -U commit_id
```

Answer (score 1):

`git show` will show the last commit, `git show <commit_id>` will show the specific commit.